# ETL that do not load some lines from a txt file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, etl

I have a C# that extracts 40 millions lines from a `.txt` file. These lines are loaded in SQL Server.

It loads almost all the lines but around a dozen of them. Every month I have to load this file and always the same problem but with different lines. And the lines do not have anything different from the others. Is my C# code the problem?

If I run the code again with the same file, I have the same problem with the same lines.

```
private static DataTable CriaDataTableCNPJ()
{
    DataTable tabelaCNPJ = new DataTable();
    tabelaCNPJ.Columns.Add(Constantes.nuCNPJ, typeof(string));
    tabelaCNPJ.Columns.Add(Constantes.noRazaoSocial, typeof(string));
    tabelaCNPJ.Columns.Add(Constantes.dtAbertura, typeof(DateTime));
    tabelaCNPJ.Columns.Add(Constantes.noFantasia, typeof(string));
    tabelaCNPJ.Columns.Add(Constantes.coCnaePrincipal, typeof(string));
    tabelaCNPJ.Columns.Add(Constantes.noMunicipio, typeof(string));
    tabelaCNPJ.Columns.Add(Constantes.sgUF, typeof(string));
    tabelaCNPJ.Columns.Add(Constantes.coNaturezaJuridica, typeof(string));
    tabelaCNPJ.Columns.Add(Constantes.noSituacaoCadastral, typeof(string));
    tabelaCNPJ.Columns.Add(Constantes.dtSituacaoCadastral, typeof(DateTime));
    tabelaCNPJ.Columns.Add(Constantes.noPorte, typeof(string));
    tabelaCNPJ.Columns.Add(Constantes.noLogradouro, typeof(string));
    tabelaCNPJ.Columns.Add(Constantes.txComplementoEndereco, typeof(string));
    tabelaCNPJ.Columns.Add(Constantes.noBairro, typeof(string));
    tabelaCNPJ.Columns.Add(Constantes.coCep, typeof(string));
    tabelaCNPJ.Columns.Add(Constantes.nuTelefone, typeof(string));

    return tabelaCNPJ;
}

private void CarregaArquivoCNPJ(string arquivoCNPJ)
{
    Arquivo arquivo = new Arquivo();

    arquivo.RegistraArquivo(arquivoCNPJ, Constantes.ConexaoSQLCNPJ, Constantes.ProcedureCNPJ03);

    sr = new StreamReader(arquivoCNPJ);//, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));

    DataTable tabelaCNPJ = CriaDataTableCNPJ();
    string linha = "";
    int contaLinha = 0;
    linha = sr.ReadLine();

    while (linha != null || !sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        try
        {
            contaLinha++;
            {
                using (StreamWriter sww = new StreamWriter(@"c:\TEMP\logLinhas.txt", true))
                {
                    sww.WriteLine(linha);
                }

            }

            if (linha.Length != 500)
            {
                arquivo.RegistraLog(arquivo.nuArquivo, Constantes.ConexaoSQLCNPJ, Constantes.ProcedureCNPJ05, contaLinha, linha, Constantes.tabelaCNPJ);
                InsereDiferencaLinha(linha);
                linha = sr.ReadLine();

            }
            else
            {
                //Cria nova linha no DataTable
                DataRow linhaTabela = tabelaCNPJ.NewRow();

                linhaTabela[Constantes.nuCNPJ] = linha.Substring(0, 14).Trim();
                linhaTabela[Constantes.noRazaoSocial] = linha.Substring(14, 115).Trim();

                //Valida o campo de data
                if (linha.Substring(130, 10).Trim() != "")
                {
                    linhaTabela[Constantes.dtAbertura] = linha.Substring(130, 10).Trim();
                }
                else
                {
                    linhaTabela[Constantes.dtAbertura] = Constantes.data;
                }

                linhaTabela[Constantes.noFantasia] = linha.Substring(140, 55).Trim();
                linhaTabela[Constantes.coCnaePrincipal]= linha.Substring(195, 7).Trim();
                linhaTabela[Constantes.sgUF] = linha.Substring(206, 2).Trim();
                linhaTabela[Constantes.noMunicipio] = linha.Substring(208, 35).Trim();
                linhaTabela[Constantes.coNaturezaJuridica] = linha.Substring(202, 4).Trim();
                linhaTabela[Constantes.noSituacaoCadastral] = linha.Substring(243, 20).Trim();
                linhaTabela[Constantes.dtSituacaoCadastral] = linha.Substring(263, 10).Trim();
                linhaTabela[Constantes.noPorte] = linha.Substring(288, 30).Trim();
                linhaTabela[Constantes.noLogradouro] = linha.Substring(318, 50).Trim();
                linhaTabela[Constantes.txComplementoEndereco] = linha.Substring(368, 60).Trim();
                linhaTabela[Constantes.noBairro] = linha.Substring(428, 40).Trim();
                linhaTabela[Constantes.coCep] = linha.Substring(468, 8).Trim();
                linhaTabela[Constantes.nuTelefone] = linha.Substring(476).Trim();
                
                tabelaCNPJ.Rows.Add(linhaTabela);

                if (tabelaCNPJ.Rows.Count >= Constantes.LimiteBulk)
                {
                    SalvaDados(ref tabelaCNPJ, Constantes.ConexaoSQLCNPJ, Constantes.ProcedureCNPJ02);
                    tabelaCNPJ.Clear();
                }
                linha = sr.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            InsereDiferencaLinha(linha);
            CEPSOUtils.RegistrarErroRotina(Constantes.NomeProjeto, erro.Message + "\n" + linha);
        }
    }
    SalvaDados(ref tabelaCNPJ, Constantes.ConexaoSQLCNPJ, Constantes.ProcedureCNPJ02);

    sr.Close();
    sr.Dispose();
    sw.Close();
    sw.Dispose();
    tabelaCNPJ.Clear();

    arquivo.RegistraFimCarga(arquivo.nuArquivo, true, Constantes.ConexaoSQLCNPJ, Constantes.ProcedureCNPJ04);
   
    arquivo.LimpaPastaDestino(Constantes.arquivoCNPJ);
}

public static void SalvaDados(ref DataTable tabela, string conexao, string procedure)
{
    using (SqlConnection connSQL = new SqlConnection(conexao))
    {
        connSQL.Open();
        SqlTransaction trans = connSQL.BeginTransaction();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedure, connSQL, trans))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 3600; // 1 HORA
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table", tabela);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            trans.Commit();
        }
        trans.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Below some example of the lines that happens the problem:

```
34256638000100GUSTAVO LACKESKI SUIGH DESENVOLVIMENTO DE SISTEMAS                                                                 M18.07.2019GS Tecnologia                                          62015012135SPSAO PAULO                          ATIVA               18.07.2019748080727974801MICROEMPRESA               R  FRANCISCA JULIA                                   277            APT   181                 EDIF  Mansão F JulSANTANA                                 02403010004196869828            
35035490000176DUETTO CAFE E GELATO LTDA                                                                                          M30.09.2019DUETTO CAFE E GELATTO                                  56112032062SPSAO PAULO                          ATIVA               30.09.2019907085727190703EMPRESA DE PEQUENO PORTE   R  BARAO DO TRIUNFO                                  612            LOJA  Café                                  BROOKLIN PAULISTA                       04602002001155420157            
35268466000557MARCELO EITELBERG AZEVEDO LANCHONETE                                                                               M22.10.2019Zapzap Doces e Lanches                                 56112032135SPSAO PAULO                          BAIXADA             04.06.2020795081552779501MICROEMPRESA               R  SETE DE ABRIL                                     230                  Salão 133                             REPUBLICA                               01044000004196869828
```

Comment: How do you know they're missing? How do you know they went missing in the C#?

Comment: Also, that is fake/altered data you posted there right?

Comment: Have you checked error logs for your application? Also, inserting strings into `DateTime` seems suspicious.

Comment: Do you have the problem if you try and load *just* the errored lines? If you code works for 39+ million lines a skips a few the most likely situation is some odd data... regardless its a debugging issue, no one can glance at your code and spot this sort of issue.

Comment: Any object you call `.Close()` or `.Dispose()` on is probably an `IDisposable` object and those should be wrapped with `using (...) {...}` to ensure proper handling. You also invoke `sw.Close();` and `sw.Dispose();` inside `CarregaArquivoCNPJ` but it's not clear where `sw` comes from - that could be interfering with other parts of your code.